# HTML In Textbox Error

Tags: asp.net, html, textbox

I'm trying to allow HTML in my asp textbox but when I go as much as clicking the button it returns with this error:

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 404."

One the serverside I am using `Server.HtmlEncode` to encode the HTML in the textbox but still getting no result. I tried using break points, `AutoEventWireup="false"`, `ValidateRequest="false"`, and setting the page validation to false in the web.config. I also tried using `ValidateRequest="false"` on the page it's self. It's also returning this error `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$testBox="<test")`. The server side and *client* side code is below:

```
--Client side--
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="testBox" />
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="testHtmlEncode" />

--Server side--
protected void testHtmlEncode(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
console.write(Server.HtmlEncode(testBox.Text));
}
```

Comment: can you disable custom errors so that you get the full error message?

Comment: Can you post more of your .aspx code? Are you using UpdatePanels and Triggers?

Comment: @Knaģis they're already disabled. This is on my local computer testing it.

Comment: @Rob it's just a empty page for testing. There isn't a updatepanel or triggers.

Comment: @Rob please view the updated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with this aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" ValidateRequest="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtValue"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="submit"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

this .aspx.cs

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(txtValue.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` in your web.config

Along with `ValidateRequest="false"` on the page.

Add the `ID="btnSubmit"` to you button

**EDIT:**

First, I would Google your original error. You should be able to make that work. Try stopping the development web server and re-running (icon in your taskbar).

https://www.google.com/?q=A+potentially+dangerous+Request.Form+value+was+detected+from+the+client

For a jQuery solution:

In .aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
  public static void MyMethod(string myTextBoxValue)
  {
    //do something
  }
```

In .aspx

```
var txtValue= $('#<%=testBox.ClientID%>').val();
        if (!txtValue) {
            txtValue= 0;
        }
        var objJSON = {
            myTextBoxValue: txtValue
        };
        var encoded = JSON.stringify(objJSON);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MyMethod",
  data: encoded,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

**EDIT 2:**
Make sure you aren't doing straight sql calls with whatever is in the text box, you will open yourself open to sql inject attacks. That's why asp.net was blocking the "<" in the first place.

**EDIT 3**
Not sure if it would matter, but your asp:Button has no ID attribute

Comment: I already have ValidateRequest="false" on the page, I'll try the httpRuntime. I was hoping to only have to disable it on one page.

Comment: The site is actually crashing now, I can't even test it with the httpRuntime.

Comment: You have to fallback to 2.0 validation mode in order for it to work. By default 4.0 validates all requests to protect against attacks. http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147

Comment: It shouldn't crash because of that. What error are you getting? Try cleaning your solution and rebuilding?

Comment: I rebuild the solution but it just turns on and shuts basically. I'm not even getting a error. Do you know of a javascript or jQuery method to do this in? That way I don't have to disable the validation so  I don't have to worry about attacks.